# Sealing Unused Vent Area

Tags: sealing

Wondering how to seal off an unused air dryer vent opening to the exterior wall. My husband has just stuffed insulation in there and said it will be fine but it's connected to the rest of the interior ceiling insulation. The gyprock ceiling would put up over it. Wondering about moisture? The vent part on the outside wall has a hood with vent grille cover. I am extremely allergic to mold. Thanks

Comment: the is a lid (cap) for that

Answer (score 2):

Make him get one of those, to properly close the vent.

[image: vent cap]

Answer (score 1):

the vent exit should be weatherproof, so blocking the airflow is all that's needed

Comment: Thanks so simple and helpful!